# Mega menu is hidden by other items on my magento website

Tags: css, magento, drop-down-menu, slider, themes

My site http://www.acuity-sports.com

I'm having problems getting the mega menu to show over the rest of the content on the website.  the slider cover up the mega menu and if you go to http://www.acuity-sports.com/volleyball.html other content on the site covers up the mega menu as well.

I've tried changing my theme.css code for the header-bottom to z-index 99 w/o any luck

Here is my header.phtml

```
global $var_yttheme; 

?>
<?php /*
<div id="yt_header" class="wrap">*/ ?>
<div class="clearfix main-top">
    <div class="header-mobi">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar" type="button">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks', false) ?>
                        <!--<strong><?php //echo $this->getWelcome() ?></strong>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="header-logo">
            <a class="logo" title="Magento Commerce" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
                <img alt="Magento Commerce" src="<?php echo $var_yttheme->skinurl();?>/images/<?php echo $var_yttheme->getParam('sitestyle');?>/logo-home.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>  

        <!-- BEGIN: Main Navigation -->
        <!-- <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">    -->
        <div class="header-nav">
            <!-- <div class="navbar-inner"> -->
                <div class="container">
                        <div class="header-nav-inner">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span12" data-normal="span12" data-tablet="span12" data-stablet="span12">
                                        <div id="yt_mainnav_mobi" class="clearfix">
                                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mobinav') ?>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                </div>
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
        <!-- END: Main Navigation -->

    </div>  


    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12"  data-normal="span12" data-tablet="span12" data-stablet="span12" >

                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <a class="logo" title="Magento Commerce" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
                            <img alt="Magento Commerce" src="<?php echo $var_yttheme->skinurl();?>/images/<?php echo $var_yttheme->getParam('sitestyle');?>/logo-home.png"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- BEGIN: Search -->

                        <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('mini-cartpro') ?>

                    <!-- END: Search -->    

                    <!-- BEGIN: Search -->
                    <div class="top-search">
                        <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END: Search -->        
                    <div class="currency-language">                                         
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency'); ?>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="yt-quick-access" >
                        <div class="quick-access">
                            <div class="shop-access <?php echo (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() )?'notlogin':'islogin' ?> ">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks', false) ?>
                                <!--<strong><?php //echo $this->getWelcome() ?></strong>-->

                                <?php if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?> 
                                <ul class="li-add"> 
                                    <li class="last item-li4">                                  
                                        <a title="Log In" href="javascript:void(0)">Log In</a>
                                        <div class="login-quick" style="display:none">
                                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_mini_login') ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>       
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div id="header-bottom" div class="header-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12"  data-normal="span12" data-       tablet="span12" data-stablet="span12" >


                    <div class="header-nav">
                        <div class="header-nav-inner">
                            <div id="yt_mainnav"     class="clearfix">
                                <?php  
                                if($var_yttheme-      >getParam('menustyle')=='mega'){
                                    echo $this-    >getChildHtml('megaMenu');
                                }else{
                                    echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu');
                                } 
                                ?>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>                      
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: find <div class="sm_megamenu_dropdown_3columns   bg-custom" style="display: none; z-index: 9999999;"> and apply  z-index

Comment: You are my hero!  Thank you very much!